# using Jira REST Java Client API i get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in eclipse, but not with ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant, version-control, jira, nosuchmethoderror

Must be the way Eclipse is set up. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.headerValueToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.writeOutBoundHeaders(DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.java:271)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.headerValueToString was removed from the Jersey library after its 1.7 release:

http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/commits/archive/2011-06/message/12

Here are some options:

1. Replace your current version of Jersey and with [an older version of Jersey](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client/):
2. Use a newer version of the JIRA REST client. I don't know if any newer versions support the change to the Jersey API.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "headerValueToString" method is supported in [jersey-client-1.5.jar](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/index.html). Some later versions don't support the method yet, such as jersey-client-1.15.jar.

Comment: It seems this has better be left as a comment. Please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use "jersey-apache-client-1.8.jar" downloaded from "http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client/1.8/" and it works well